# How to use service call in more than one one component?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-services

I have to use these services call in more than one component but i'm having problem in reusing the code. How to make this code reusable?

```
//For Permanent Countries
this.service.getCountries().subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.permanentCountries = response;
});

//For Temporary Countries
this.service.getCountries().subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.temporaryCountries = response;
});

//For Genders
this.service.getGenders().subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.genders = response;
});
```

Comment: can you add more code? Add part of your service and part of your component

Comment: @Ashutosh by service call, do you mean sharing the same HTTP request?